# Change the look of the button - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to change the look of the button with two images, one Normal state and the other with the highlighted/selected state on selection, but i don't know how, i have tried this:

```
   UIImage *buttonImage_Home = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upload.png"];

   UIImage *stretchableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImage_Home stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];

   UIButton *homeButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];

   [homeButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It works, but i don't know how to add second image if pressed/touched, please help me out

Comment: [homeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these according to your requirement.

```
UIControlStateNormal 
UIControlStateHighlighted                 // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
UIControlStateDisabled  
UIControlStateSelected
```

Comment: Thanks just what i was looking for, i cant accept all answers, but +1 to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The same way, but for state `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Answer (score 1):

You should set an image for highlighted state. For example:

```
[homeButton setBackgroundImage:pressedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `UIControlStateHighlighted`

```
[homeButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```